# abs not working on lucee coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using the below to format the number I get after calulating the % increase or decrease, which means this number can be positive or a negative number. The below works fine on Coldfusion, but on Lucee it throws an error - can't cast [- 6.50] string to a number value. Any idea how to workaround this.

```
<cfif money_deposit lt 0>
    <cfset testVar = abs(NumberFormat(money_deposit,'99.99'))>
<cfelse>
    <cfset testVar = NumberFormat(money_deposit,'99.99')>
</cfif>
```

Comment: If money_forecast is numeric, try switching the numberFormat and abs functions around.

Comment: Its not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove any empty spaces. In any case, it is good practice to first test whether the input parameter is numeric.

```
<!--- Remove any spaces --->
<cfset money_deposit = REreplace(money_deposit,"\s","","all")>
<cfif isNumeric(money_deposit)>
    <cfif money_deposit lt 0>
        <cfset testVar = abs(NumberFormat(money_deposit,'-99.99'))>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset testVar = NumberFormat(money_deposit,'99.99')>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`javaCast`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/javacast.html)

```
<cfif money_deposit lt 0>
  <cfset testVar = abs(NumberFormat(javaCast("float", money_deposit),'99.99'))>
<cfelse>
  <cfset testVar = NumberFormat(money_deposit,'99.99')>
</cfif>
```

Comment: The above does not seem to work on all scenarios, it is working on some and not other other negative numbers not sure why

Comment: can't cast [- 6.50] string to a number value

Comment: are you sure the javacast is there? I've never seen javaCast fail to cast to a type without throwing an error on the cast itself.

Comment: Yes it is there on the page

Comment: Anything else that could cause that error? It is basically, trying to format a negative -6.50 which is a string to number

Comment: Is the string you are trying to cast `-6.50` or `[-6.50]`?

Answer (score 0):

Number format returns a string
http://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/numberformat.html

The problem is your formatting mask "99.99" means return a formatted number with two characters before the decimal point, the string value you are getting back is "- 6.50", with an extra space. Try using a mask for numberformat of either "9.99" or "09.99"